# Why does this SQl injection only work together with AND ''='?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I'm testing some SQL stuff on sqlzoo.net/hack and I'm not getting why

```
' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '__w%') AND ''='
```

does work for the SQL injection and

```
' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '__w%')
```

not. Why is it necessary to put this last

```
AND ''='
```

?

Also i guess that these SQL injections are very 'old' and won't work. Are there newer methods and are there sites where someone can learn this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to close the '.

The code that checks for the password may be something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM usersPassword where password = '" + TEXTINPUT + "';"
```

If you want to simply go in, `' OR ''='` will do the job.
The complete query will be

```
"SELECT * FROM usersPassword where password = '' OR ''='';"
```

which is an always true condition.

The example on the website does something more. It checks how the password of a certain user look like, if a certain character is present you will know by the fact that you're able to log in.

EDIT:

In your case the final query will be

```
"SELECT * FROM usersPassword where password = '' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '%w%') AND ''=''"
```

if you don't put the AND

`"SELECT * FROM usersPassword where password = '' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '%w%')'"` ----> which does not close !

Comment: But why do we need AND ' '=' in addition? This is just one more thing that needs to be true and the previous condition also needs to be true. It would be like if(true AND true) then login. So why not just if(true)?

Comment: 2 reasons: 1) you need to escape the ' character, and ''=' gives you that 2) the first condition is not always true ! it's true only if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '%w%'), meaning the password for jake contains a w

Comment: Ahh, the escape was the thing I missed. I didn't realize in first place that you can't close the order ' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '__w%') with the ' . I knew that the first condition is not always true but the AND ' '=' is always true. So it would have no influence an the only reason is to escape the ' character. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because it will concat to the input parameter which mean that your first query will be

OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='jake' AND password LIKE '%w%') ***AND ''=''*** OR''='{somevalue}'

which always true